# Designing a thin Object Oriented Query Language for SQL

Tags: java, oop, orm

Given the following class :

```
class People {
.....
String getName();

int getAge();
...
}
```

I want to query my database for all people whose age is greater than 20. So I would like to write something like getPeople(AGE>20).. In short I want to write an object oriented query which is easy to read. We can have complex selection criteria for querying but for the sake of simplicity we restrict it to a single variable. In my setting I would be fetching this detail from SQL by converting the object oriented query into a relational query. I need to design this but could not think of something clean. If you have patience then please read further.

OLD QUESTION (probably wasn't framed well)

I am working in Java with SQL database. The database queries are usually very simple in our case. The aim is to write queries in object oriented language and then those can be transformed into sql queries by a generic module.

Now inserting, deleting an object can be easily designed like - public void delete(DBObject obj). The problem is however in querying and I need your help in designing it. So assume we have a account object, and I want to insert an account object into database - in this case I will be calling public void insert(Account account); What if I want to retrieve all account objects based on specific account type or whose account name does not starts with some string str. Ideally, we should be able to query on all behavior which are exposed (which return value) in account class.

I can see the need for a query builder but could not come up with a neat contract which can easily be used.

P.S. - I am attempting this only to improve my understanding. So a reference to hibernate or any orm is probably not my answer. I have tried to dig in some source code at git but usually they are too big :(

EDIT :
Matt suggested Specification design pattern in his comments and that really simplifies the things to some extent. One of the problems I have been facing is to formulate the queries in an easy fashion which are easy to read. Let C1 C2 C3 C4 be some conditions then what this pattern allows me is that I can easily write any complex query using universal gates - and,or,not in a easy way.
Now the problem is to model this individual condition say C1. So if there is an account class which has a function public int yearsSinceAccountWasOpend() Now I want to retrieve accounts which are at-least 7 years old, so how should I do it? (some annotation trick?)

Comment: My first thought would be using the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) with some translator to generate WHERE clauses from the specification objects. Can't be any more specific than that right now, it's a broad suggestion for a broad question ;)

Comment: it actually looks quite good.. let me study it more and see if it fits in.. thanks..

Comment: Looks like you are trying to build a DSL to abstract over SQL in an object-oriented manner. A starting point could be [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) - it has a very fluent API, you can borrow some ideas and maybe build upon it.